# How to make a donation to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, donation

Not sure if Stack Overflow needs donations or if its rich. But since I get help from the community, I'd be happy to make a donation. How do I do this?

Comment: I guess answering some questions would work :)

Comment: I can forward you the address of their bank account in Switzerland, would that suffice? ;)

Answer (score 12):

Charity come in many forms. Money is not the only form of donation. In my opinion, helping others when you can is pretty much the biggest type of donation anyone can offer.

Comment: That's exactly what I was going to say. Your time, your knowledge and your ideas are what make the site thrive. Just contribute those.

Comment: My donation, rather penance, is in this form, i.e. inviting and training more unpaid jedis for SO - Read this one-pager for more: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1VT06byhPKCnbAauKaJkLWghZVaT0MRvXb49kiUCVvD4/edit